# function inside document ready jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to put this function within a `document.ready` function in jQuery:

```
$('#font').change(function () {
    var selectedValue2 = $(this).val();
    if (selectedValue2 === 'Standard') {
        $('.3Dtxt').hide();
        $('.inlinetxt').hide();
    } else {
        if (selectedValue2 === '3D') {
            $('.3Dtxt').show();
            $('.inlinetxt').hide();
        }
        $('#' + selectedValue2).slideToggle();
    } if (selectedValue2 === 'Hiline') {
        $('.3Dtxt').hide();
        $('.inlinetxt').show();
    }
    $('#' + selectedValue2).slideToggle();

});
```

Could someone please help me out please?

This doesn't work either:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#font').change(function () {
        var selectedValue2 = $(this).val();
        if (selectedValue2 === 'Standard') {
            $('.3Dtxt').hide();
            $('.inlinetxt').hide();
        } else {
            if (selectedValue2 === '3D') {
                $('.3Dtxt').show();
                $('.inlinetxt').hide();
            }
            $('#' + selectedValue2).slideToggle();
        } if (selectedValue2 === 'Hiline') {
            $('.3Dtxt').hide();
            $('.inlinetxt').show();
        }
        $('#' + selectedValue2).slideToggle();

    });

});
```

Comment: Uhm, did you read the manual ?

Comment: Er, you just put it inside a document ready function.

Comment: Wrap it inside of `$(document).ready(function(){…})`…

Comment: @Luxelin, i did that and it stopped working!

Comment: Edit your post to contain the code that stopped working. We can't do much to help you otherwise.

Comment: That code looks fine. Is your question "why doesn't this code work?"

Comment: @Andy, yeah you could say that!

Comment: um, place the js to your first function UNDER the elements `#font` ( say just before the closing `</body>` tag and try that first

Comment: You buried the lede. Add your HTML to [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3kf4/) and tell us what your expected output is meant to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap document ready tags around it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#font').change(function(){
        var selectedValue2 = $(this).val();
        if (selectedValue2 === 'Standard') {
            $('.3Dtxt').hide();
            $('.inlinetxt').hide();
        } else {
            if (selectedValue2 === '3D') {
            $('.3Dtxt').show();
            $('.inlinetxt').hide();
            }
            $('#' + selectedValue2).slideToggle();
        }if (selectedValue2 === 'Hiline') {
            $('.3Dtxt').hide();
            $('.inlinetxt').show();
            }
            $('#' + selectedValue2).slideToggle();

    });
});
```

but if you mean you want it to fire on document ready, you just need to change your first line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var selectedValue2 = $('#font').val();
        if (selectedValue2 === 'Standard') {
            $('.3Dtxt').hide();
            $('.inlinetxt').hide();
        } else {
            if (selectedValue2 === '3D') {
            $('.3Dtxt').show();
            $('.inlinetxt').hide();
            }
            $('#' + selectedValue2).slideToggle();
        }if (selectedValue2 === 'Hiline') {
            $('.3Dtxt').hide();
            $('.inlinetxt').show();
            }
            $('#' + selectedValue2).slideToggle();

    });
```

Comment: why none of them work? am I missing something? the only way it works is when I use my first code!

Comment: try using `==` instead of `===`?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this ?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Your Code
});
```

Comment: Why would someone -1 this? There is absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I don't now really :(

Comment: It was hastily posted and was vague. The edit cleared it up.